# Floated images popping out of max-width paragraph

Tags: css, overflow

I have images floated in paragraph text in a dynamically sized div. Everything works great until the div gets to it's max-width size, then the images "pop" out to the sides. I've tried setting the div to `overflow:hidden`, but that just cuts the image off. I want the image to "lock" in place once the div get's to it's max-width.

I tried clearing the float, but that didn't have an affect.

```
div{
margin: 0px auto;
max-width: 604px;
width: 100%;
}

img{
float:right;
}
```

Comment: do you have an example of this?

Comment: http://claytonsalem.com/correllglass/front/

Answer (score 0):

Change this section of your css code:

```
.entry-content img.alignright, .entry-content .wp-caption.alignright {
    margin-right: -60px;
}
```

To

```
.entry-content .wp-caption.alignright {
    margin-right: -60px;
}
```

That will solve your problem!